# Generate rule for all direct descendants in PostCSS

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, postcss

I would like to create a PostCSS plugin, where I can generate a new rule for all direct descendants.

For example, I would like to generate rule:

```
div > * {
   color: black;
}
```

For all `divs`, which are `display: block`.

I didn't find a good example how to do this.

```
module.exports = () => {
  let skipped = Symbol("isSkipped"); // skipped flag
  let counter = Symbol("skippedCounter"); // counter for test "isSkipped" optimization

  function generateRule(decl) {
    let rules = decl.parent;
    rules[counter] = Number.isInteger(rules[counter]) ? rules[counter] : 0;

    if (!rules[skipped]) {
      if (decl.value === "block") {
        
        // generate a new rule here

        rules[skipped] = true;
        rules[counter]++;
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    postcssPlugin: "postcss-example-plugin",
    Declaration: {
      display: (decl) => generateRule(decl),
    },
  };
};
module.exports.postcss = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain on what part you're looking for, so if this doesn't answer your question, feel free to clarify and I'll update the response.

Here's some code that I think does what you want - though it's mostly what you've already written without the optimizations:

```js
module.exports = {
  postcssPlugin: "add-rule-to-descendants",
  Declaration: {
    // https://postcss.org/api/#declarationprocessor
    display(displayDecl, { Rule, Declaration }) {
      if (displayDecl.value === 'block') {
        // Add the new rule after the parent https://postcss.org/api/#rule-after
        displayDecl.parent.after(
          new Rule({
            selector: `${displayDecl.parent.selector} > *`,
            nodes: [
              new Declaration({ prop: 'color', value: 'black' })
            ]
          })
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've also prepped the example with some quick tests on Repl.it https://repl.it/@dcwither/postcss-all-decendants-rule#plugin.js.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I was looking for :)